# Adding multiple views to a container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am looking at adding numerous TableViews to an existing UI View Controller.

I have seen https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html which seems to be the way I'm meant to go.

However, **my question is can I embed more than one TableView to a single ContainerView?**

My app does a variety of tests for which there are results. After each test completes I want to add a TableView so they appear underneath each other neatly.

**Is this possible?**

Comment: What do you mean by container View? There is a container view controller ..which is a specific thing..but there is no special container view..any standard UIView can be a container view in practice.

Comment: I've tried to explain it a bit more in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844921/add-a-uitableview-to-an-existing-viewcontroller

Comment: Bit harsh giving minus votes when I'm seeking help on the best way to approach something.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  You can do two things:

> ONE View Controller - MANY Table Views (as subview of the root view)

or

> ONE Container Controller - MANY ChildViewControllers using VC containment (and each has one Table View )

Comment: Can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844921/add-a-uitableview-to-an-existing-viewcontroller and let me know where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: That question is correctly answered by @Gavin Bunney. Is it related to this one somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could do in ViewDidLoad for a UIViewController subclass.

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

CGRect frame = self.view.frame;

// this container shall hold the two tables that I am going to add later
// container shall share the same size as view controller's "view"
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

frame.size.height = frame.size.height / 2; // I want to fit two table view vertically to cover the container view

UITableView *tableView1 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
tableView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
// ...
// ...
// Assign more table view properties here
// ...
// ...
[container addSubview:tableView1];

frame.origin.y = frame.size.height; // update coordinates for the second table view

UITableView *tableView2 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
tableView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
// ...
// ...
// Assign more table view properties here
// ...
// ...
[container addSubview:tableView2];

[self.view addSubview:container];
```

you shall have to set Delegates for all tableviews to make them work properly, but this should give you something to get going. (I have added some different background colors to distinguish between both the tableviews)

Comment: And what exactly is the point of having that container view? It is redundant, serves no purpose.
Also, frame.origin.y = frame.size.height; // update coordinates for the second table view - will fail because you can't set member of struct, you need to create a new one.

Comment: frame.origin.y = frame.size.height; wont fail because frame is a local variable. You can leave the container view and add directly to self.view if you want to, it there only for clarification on how you can add multiple views to a container.

Comment: And I thought, I was done with frames a very long time ago. Apparently, the UIView somehow protects struct members 8-/  Thank you for this, you sir are right :)

Comment: This is what I have so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844921/add-a-uitableview-to-an-existing-viewcontroller