# Add a UITableView to an existing ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, addsubview, uitableview

I'm trying to add a `UITableView` to an existing `UIViewController` programmatically.

My `run.h` file has this:

```
@interface runTests : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {NSTimer *Timer;}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
```

My app runs through a speed test and at the end of the test I'm trying to add a TableView to the View. At the moment I have this:

```
-(void)addSpeedTable {


    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    self.tableView.rowHeight = 45;
    self.tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 22;
    self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 22;

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];


}

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Testing";

        return cell;
    }
```

The app never makes it into the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method but does make it into the other two above. I can't see any error in the Xcode output.

Anything I need to be doing here:

[image]

When the app fails all I get is this:

[image]

Comment: You can catch the actual exception by adding an exception breakpoint - quick guide here: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: I've done this yet I still only get this. I set a breakpoint on "return 1;" for numberOfRowsInSection. The app gets to this breakpoint. When I continue it fails and gives the screenshot above

Comment: Make sure you add a breakpoint for `All Exceptions` - it should then break on whatever line is causing the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` to occur :)

Comment: I tried this @GavinBunney but it didn't break, it just ended on the same screen as before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If width of `UITableView` is zero, it will never call `datasource`

So change your code like this

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Good luck!

Comment: I've added this with no luck, still crashes

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer It crashes?  You never said that in your question.

Comment: I said it "never made it to the CFRAIP", which I guess was my way of saying it crashed. I'll add the view I get when it fails

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer: let catch all exception to find out where carsh is. The above code is so simple, it can make crash

Comment: I have "catch all exceptions" turned on but it doesn't catch any. very frustrating

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer: really hard to know what happened with your code. Please make it more clear, show full code, it will make everyone understand flow of your code and help you

Comment: @VietHung I did a ton more testing last night and concluded, rather embarrassingly, that it had NOTHING to do with the addSubView code :(

Answer (score 2):

You should init your UITableView with a frame (and optionally a style), or at least define the frame somewhere.

For example:

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the property `tableView` to the instance you are creating in the `addSpeedTable` method, then reference it using `self.tableView`.

```
-(void)addSpeedTable {
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    self.tableView.rowHeight = 45;
    self.tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 22;
    self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 22;

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

**Edit**

As pointed out by the other answers, you'll probably need to set the frame on the `UITableView` as well:

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: Hi Gavin, I've tried this with no luck! Any idea how I can get more details on the error? The lack of Xcode feedback is frustrating

Comment: try adding [self.tableview reloadData]; to the end.

Comment: I've updated the OP with your changes and this still isn't working for me. I did try the reloadData, to no avail

Comment: Can you add your entire ViewController implementation file? Wondering if the timing of the `self.view` might be nil when you are trying to add the `tableView` to it

Comment: You're right, I think it is related to the self.view @GavinBunney. I added an property of a UIView and initialized it at the beginning of my code. It didn't fail but the TableView took up the entire screen from the first second (covered my existing view. I don't want the TableView to appear until I call it

Answer (score 1):

You use init method to initialize a view, which means the view's frame is CGRectZero.
So the numberOfRowsInSection is called but SDK finds no cell need to be shown as the frame is CGRectZero.

-(void)addSpeedTable {

```
.....

tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

}

What's more you should assign your tableView to the property by self.tableView = tableView or your tableView property will never be valid state.

Comment: I've added the "init with frame" code by @VietHung but this makes no difference

Comment: Is my .h file correct? I haven't synthesized the "tableView" from the .h file

Comment: You need to register the  @"newCell" to your tableview when it's initialized with [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"newCell"].

Answer (score 0):

You can add breakpoint at the thirdLine, and print out the frame see if one of its bounds is 0.

Comment: The output is TableView Frame {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have declare the wrong syntax. I can't upload image, So notice the difference the code below. The capitalization may be the problem.
    {
        // 服务条款
        static NSString * cellId = @"justCommon";

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newCell";
}
```